# How to print the content of an object

Tags: java

When I start my program, it gives me a link to an object, while I want to get the content. Where's my mistake?

I think the problem lies in `storage.addRecord(record)` in `ReaderXls.class`.

Result:

```
 Reading is over 
 Start reading from Storage
 work2obj.Record@2910d926
```

.

```
  public class Start {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Start reading from Xls");
                ReaderXls read = new ReaderXls();
                Storage storage;
                storage = read.ReadXls("Text1obj",0,1);
                System.out.println("Reading is over");
                System.out.println("Start reading from Storage");
                System.out.println(storage.getRecord(1));
            }
        }
```

.

```
  public class Storage
    {
        List<Record> record;
        public Storage(){
            this.record = new ArrayList<Record>();
        }
```

.

```
  public Record getRecord(int number){
            return this.record.get(number);
        }    
      }
```

.

```
  public class ReaderXls {
  public Storage ReadXls(String sfilename,int firstColumn, int lastColumn){
            Storage storage = new Storage();
            try {      
  Record record = new Record(j, Integer.parseInt(ContentCount), RowContent);
                    storage.addRecord(record);
  }
 }
```

Comment: perhaps get(0), or manage an iterator on the List.

Comment: nevermind, i have near 40 elements in storage. question not about that.

Comment: Objects don't 'contain' anything except primitives and base objects, and they are much more likely to *refer* to objects rather than classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should implement the `toString` method in the `Record` class to return a string containing the data you want to display.

By default, since your class doesn't implement `toString`, `Object.toString()` gets called, which returns `<the name of the class>@<the object's hashcode>`

Answer (score 4):

You need to Override [**toString**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method inside `Record` class to get the content of object. 
It Returns a string representation of the object.

> If you want to represent any object as a string, toString() method
>   comes into existence. **The toString() method returns the string
>   representation of the object.** If you print any object, java compiler
>   internally invokes the toString() method on the object. So overriding
>   the toString() method, returns the desired output, it can be the state
>   of an object etc. depends on your implementation.

Read more about it's implementation from [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString%28%29-method).